# Intermittent Query Timeout via API

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, query

Recently we've seen some intermittent query timeouts via the API.  (i.e. SF queries submitted via inbound API requests).  These are queries that consistently take less than 10 seconds when executed via console or Workbench.  And most of the time in production they complete just fine, in about 30-40 seconds, including transmission and any processing overhead.  So not even close to the 120 second limit.  But then sometimes they time out.

This has happened recently w/ two different orgs, two different queries, on two different SF instances, and two different APIs (one REST, one SOAP).

My question is: what might be making them take much longer some times than others?  I understand that this might depend on the overall load on the SF instance we're querying.  But is there anything else specific to my org that comes into play here?  What can I try to avoid this?

We noticed in one case that if we changed the time the query happened (this is operating on a schedule) the problem seemed to go away.  It had been running at a time when at least 2 scheduled batch processes were running in the org.  We didn't think that should matter, but we changed it to a time when no batch jobs run, and we stopped seeing the timeouts.  Coincidence?

Note that I'm not getting the non-selective query err here.  Just a timeout.  These are not queries on very large tables.  (In both cases less than 200k rows).  So I don't think I need to optimize the queries, since they execute fine most of the time.

Thanks!

Comment: Just curious... is your batch jobs performing DML on the same objects you're querying.   

Also, maybe post the queries you are running.   

Does the timeout often happen on the first query?  From similar experiences my first guess would be an indexing issue.

Comment: @NSjonas Yes to both questions.  The query is on the Contact object in both cases, and in both cases some of the batch jobs are doing DML on contact.  Why would that slow it down this much, though?  Shouldn't queries be independent of simultaneous DMLs?

And why would you suspect indexing when it runs so fast in console?

Comment: I ended up submitting a case on this.  Support declined to help because we don't have premier support.   But the rep did say that it wasn't because of the batch jobs.